# selectOneMenu sets field to null after being changed

Tags: jsf, richfaces, seam

I try to do something that is very similar to [this](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_support.html) *richfaces* example. I have a form that describes custom ID validation in case that you have not selected one of the predefined ones, else the form will be disabled. So disabled expression for the form members would go to the next method:

```
public boolean isPredefinedValidator() {
    return !currentProjectRegField.getIdValidation().getIdType().equals(IdValidatorType.NONE);
}
```

that is invoked like this:

```
disabled="#{accountHome.isPredefinedValidator()}"
```

and here is the selector for the predefined validator:

```html
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{accountHome.currentProjectRegField.idValidation.idType}"
    rendered="#{!(empty accountHome.currentProjectRegField or empty accountHome.currentProjectRegField.idValidation)}">
    <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="customIdValidator"/>
        <s:convertEnum />
            <s:enumItem enumValue="NONE" label="#{messages['IdValidatorType_enum.NONE']}"/>
            <s:enumItem enumValue="USA_ID" label="#{messages['IdValidatorType_enum.USA_ID']}"/>
            <s:enumItem enumValue="MEXICO_ID" label="#{messages['IdValidatorType_enum.MEXICO_ID']}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The issue is, when the  method `isPredefinedValidator()` is invoked on `a4j` rerender (on disabled EL), I receive NPE.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.whatever.something.action.AccountHome.isPredefinedValidator(AccountHome.java)
```

And when I try to debug - turns out that the value that has been set from the `selectOneMenu` is null.

Does it mean that `reRender` and setting value to the variable happens async, and there is a race condition? And what is the correct solution for this case?

Comment: Make sure the attribute `currentProjectRegField` and it's inner attribute `idValidation` is initialized when the managed bean is created, otherwise you will face this NPE error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some black-magic configuration in the `rich:modalPanel` that contains the `h:selectOneMenu` resolved this issue. It goes like this `<rich:modalPanel ... domElementAttachment="form">`